# append data to open.window()

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I like to append data(JSON) I received from the server to new pop up window. I  tried what other people already posted but none of them actually works.

```
$.ajax
    ({
        url: "/receiveData",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        data:myJSON,
        dataType: "json",
        success: handledata
    });
```

so I have this ajax call and handle data

This is what i have on handledata function and I like to append this to specific id called "user" in open.html

```
var newin = window.open("open.html");
$(newin.document.body).ready(function() {
    //$(newin.document.body).append("<tr>"+ "Hello"+ "<tr>")
        newin.alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: .innerHTLM += "<tr>"+ "Hello"+ "<tr>"

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking http request in a wrong way.
When you call `window.open()` the next window does not have any data from the existing window. It's a new js instance.

The solution is to past data in url as query parameter, eg: `"open.html?data="+queryStr`, and then send http call from `<body onload="/* Your ajax call here */">` on **open.html** page.

There is how to encode json string:

```
function encode(queryStr) {
  return b.split(' ').map(i => encodeURIComponent(i)).join('+').replace(/'/g, "%27").replace(/"/g, "%22");
}
```

There is how to retrieve query string from url:
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript#answer-901144)

Comment: thx didn't think about putting ajax call on new popup window. Didn't really used the method you provided but it did solve my problem Thx a lot !